# Does Picocli support tar style argument simplification? E.g. 'tar -tvf file' vs 'tar tvf file'

Tags: picocli

Does picocli support the tar-style option simplification, for example single character options do not required to prefix a group of options with a dash.   For example the following are equivalent:

tar -t -v -f file

tar -tvf file

tar tvf file

Answer (score 2):

Yes, picocli [supports POSIX short options](https://picocli.info/#_short_posix_options) out of the box.
Specifically, option names consisting of a single "dash" `-` followed by a single character are considered POSIX short options and these may be clustered, so `tar -t -v -f FILE` is equivalent to `tar -tvfFILE`.  I believe this follows the POSIX [standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html#tag_12_02) (Guideline 5).

However, picocli will not recognize the third pattern you describe: `tar xvf FILE`: the initial leading dash or hyphen `-` character is required.

Comment: @jeff-mcclure Can you accept this answer or do you need more information?